# Can explain why there is had in the sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I had always dreamed of going and I know how fortunate I am to have had the opportunity to do so. 
Can u pls explain why there is''had'' in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It's using the [past perfect tense](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-past-perfect-tense):

> It is often used with a time expression such as *always* or *for several days*.
>
> We had always wanted to visit Canada, so last year we decided to go.

It's the past equivalent of the present perfect tense in which you would say *I* ***have*** *always dreamed of going.*

In this case, you *had* an unfulfilled desire—until (at some point in the past) you actually *did* go.

In normal usage (how we understand this kind of expression to work), to say *I* ***have*** *always dreamed of going* implies that you have never gone. (Grammatically, there's nothing wrong with continuing to say *I have always* once you've gone—but people would not understand your meaning if you did.)

It's quite possible that, having gone, you liked it so much that you want to go back—and that you continue to dream about going. But, if that's the case, we would normally switch to simply saying *I always dream of going*, dropping the use of ***have*** and ***dreamed***.

Comment: To have had the opportunity . Because first sentence start with past perfect tense. If it doesnt start with past perfect tense should we say to have the opportunity right?

Comment: @Eren55 Somebody making a speech could say, "I'm grateful to have this opportunity," yes. It would be in the present because it was currently happening.